# How authorized users to make get requests only

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have a REST API which connects to MariaSQL server.
The API is in nodeJS and based on express.

I have auth enabled that give a token to every user that sign in or sign up.
But with the token , every one could make post request or other and use every routes they want from the API.
I would like the users to be authorize to make only get requests and just myself to do other API requests (POST, DELETE...).

How can I do that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can define a middle ware like this before routes:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    );
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, PATCH, POST, GET, DELETE');
        res.status(200).json({});
    }

    next();
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but I'm quite new to express and not sure to understand how that code works. Could you explain ?